AWS ECS task fails to find container when EC2 instance is in a private subnet
I want to deploy an application in a container running on an EC2 instance using ECS. I am using Terraform to set up my resources.
My current code is as follows:
ECS task:
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "api" {
  family             = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-api"
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.task_role.arn
  memory             = var.task_memory
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name              = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-api"
      image             = "${local.ecs.image}:${var.ecr_tag}"
      cpu               = var.task_cpu
      memory            = var.task_memory
      memoryReservation = var.task_memory_reservation
      essential         = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          name          = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-rest-api-${var.container_port}-${var.protocol}",
          containerPort = var.container_port,
          hostPort      = var.host_port,
          protocol      = var.protocol,
        }
      ],
      mountPoints = var.mount_points
      volumesFrom = var.volumes_from
      environment = jsondecode(templatefile("${abspath(var.project_dir)}/task_definition_env.json", { env = local.env }))
      secrets     = jsondecode(templatefile("${abspath(var.project_dir)}/task_definition_secrets.json", { env = local.env }))
      logConfiguration = {
        "logDriver" : "awslogs",
        "options" : {
          "awslogs-create-group" : "true",
          "awslogs-group" : "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}",
          "awslogs-region" : "${var.aws_region}",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix" : "rest-api"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
}

EC2 instance:
resource "aws_instance" "api_instance" {
  ami                    = var.ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  key_name               = var.key_pair_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  subnet_id              = var.vpc.private_subnet_ids[0]
  user_data              = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/assign_cluster", { cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.this.name }))
  iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_profile.name

  metadata_options {
    http_tokens = "required"
  }

  root_block_device {
    encrypted = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_security_group.instance]
}

EC2 security group:
resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name        = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-instance"
  description = "Security group for EC2 instance"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule" "instance_all" {
  ip_protocol       = "-1"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "All egress from bastion"
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_ssh" {
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "SSH"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-ssh"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_https" {
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "HTTPS"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-https"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_custom_tcp" {
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "Custom TCP"
  from_port         = var.container_port
  to_port           = var.container_port
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-custom_tcp"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_http" {
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "HTTP"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-http"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_all_tcp" {
  ip_protocol                  = "tcp"
  security_group_id            = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description                  = "default"
  from_port                    = 0
  to_port                      = 65535
  referenced_security_group_id = aws_security_group.load_balancer.id

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-all-tcp"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "instance_rds" {
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instance.id
  description       = "RDS"
  from_port         = var.db_port
  to_port           = var.db_port
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${replace(local.name, "_", "-")}-ingress-rds"
  }
}

VPC variable
  vpc = {
    vpc_id             = "vpc-5e8f6a34d6e1b7c2f0a1b"
    public_subnet_ids  = ["subnet-7d3e4f1a2b0c8d6e5f4a", "subnet-3a4b5c6d7e8f9a0b1c2d"]
    private_subnet_ids = ["subnet-1e2f3a4b5c6d7e8f9a0", "subnet-f0e1d2c3b4a59687766"]
  }

I have checked that the subnets IDs are correct.
When I try de deploy this app, the ECS Service deployment status is failed and in the events, I see this error message.
service ecs-service-name was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster.

The task can start successfully if I deploy the EC2 instance in a public subnet like this:
resource "aws_instance" "api_instance" {
  subnet_id = var.vpc.public_subnet_ids[0]
}

How should I configure my ECS task and my EC2 instance to deploy my container in a private subnet?

I think this could be due to different issues. Does your VPC have a NAT gateway defined? Is the AMI listed as ecs-optimized? What launch type have you defined for the task?

Like said MArko, you'll need a NAT gateway to allow your subnet to access internet. try follow this, I used it successfully to setup ECS
https://medium.com/@bradford_hamilton/deploying-containers-on-amazons-ecs-using-fargate-and-terraform-part-2-2e6f6a3a957f

Have you checked in the ECS console to see how many registered instances the cluster has? I'm guessing it will be 0, because an EC2 instance in a private subnet can't access the ECS service API to register itself with the cluster. You either need a NAT gateway, or several VPC Endpoints (for ECS, ECR, etc.) to make this work.

Thank you all for your comments.
The AMI is ecs-optimized and the launch type is set to EC2.
I don't get why the NAT gateway to grant access to the internet will solve this issue. To me, it seems to be an issue inside my AWS network. It seems that ECS is lacking the permission to access the private subnet. Can someone help me clarify this?

APIs in AWS tend to be in what is know as a "public zone". This means that when you are using "public" subnets, you usually don't experience such errors. With "private" subnets, you either have to have a NAT Gateway to reach the "public zone" or you have to create the corresponding VPC endpoints.
